# How to use scikit-learn normalize data to [-1, 1]?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using scikit-learn `MinMaxScaler()` to normalize to $[0, 1]$, but I want to normalize to $[-1, 1].$ What function do I have to use to normalize this way?

Comment: You can pass `feature_range` parameter in `MinMaxScaler` to transform data to any range you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaling between `0` and `1` is simply written for an array of values `arr` = $[x_{1}, x_{2}, ...., x_{n}]$ as

```
scaled_array = (arr-arr.min())/(arr.max()-arr.min())
```

But scaling between two values can be inherited from `normalisation` in Images when values are scaled between `0` to `255` (normally).

You can write scaling as

```
scaled_values = ((val - min)*(new_max - new_min)/(max - min)) + new_min
```

where `new_min, new_max` are the maximum and minimum values you are scaling in between and `max` and `min` are the maximum and minimum values in your array.

For example if you want to scale values between `-1` and `1` for an array `[2, 5, 0]`, it reduces to

```
((arr - 0)*(1-(-1))/(5-0)) - 1 = [-0.2, 1, -1]
```

Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(image_processing)) wiki page.

**Edit:**

As pointed out rightly in comments by @AnkitSeth, `MinMaxScalar` do have `feature_range` argument you can pass on. But I am sure the internal job done by `feature_range` is the same thing as I had mentioned above.

Answer (score -2):

Try using `StandardScaler()` from `sklearn.preprocessing`.

This is the proper normalization. But we cannot give any range. 
Only mean is zero, that is for sure.